# REXML: How to add the root element in a exiting but empty file?

Tags: ruby, rexml

I have an empty XML page I've called "users.xml". I'd like to be able to create all the content using REXML.

```
require "rexml/document"
include REXML  # so that we don't have to prefix everything with REXML::...

xmlfile = File.new("users.xml")
doc = Document.new(xmlfile)

//code to save root element here...
```

It looks to me that `doc` reads first the content of "users.xml", but changes that occurred in doc do not propagate back. How do I save changes to the file?

Comment: Why do you want to use REXML? [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org) is pretty much the default standard for processing XML in Ruby.

Comment: @theTinMan, because ruby is new to me I do normally .net. I'll try Nokogiri then.

Comment: Read through, and try the tutorials for Nokogiri. Search the SO archives for the `[nokogiri]` tag if you have questions. There are a good number of excellent examples of how to do things here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You open the file:

```
doc = Document.new(xmlfile)
```

but you never read it, or write it again.

You need to use something like:

```
xmlfile = File.read("users.xml")
```

to read it, (which isn't a scalable way to do it, but that's an entirely different subject).

After you convert it to a REXML document using `doc = Document.new(xmlfile)`, you need to write it back out. You can use `File.write` or `File.open` with a block.